# Logback logger name

Tags: logging, logback

Is there a way to create a logger name using regular expressions or wild card. The reason I am asking this is; my application uses a lot of third part libraries which I don't want to append to the same log. I want a seperate appender for them. What I wanted to know was if there is a way to create a logger name by defining a wildcard of package name and then all logs from that package go to that logger
E.g.

```
<logger name="org.zookeeper.* additivity=false>
   <appender ref="aaa"/>
</logger>
```

This should make all logs from package name which starts with org.zookeeper.* to go to the above specific logger.

Does logback support this facility?

Answer (score 12):

To log all org.zookeeper subpackages to "aaa" appender, you should omit the .* at the end of logger definition:

```
<logger name="org.zookeeper" additivity=false>
    <appender ref="aaa"/>
</logger>
```